# Getting a mypy type error using pydantic generics and don't know why

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

With the following project setup

pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Joe Smith <joe.smith@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
pydantic = "^1.10.7"
mypy = "^1.3.0"

[tool.mypy]
plugins = [
    "pydantic.mypy"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

And the following code example:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

T = TypeVar("T")


class BaseModel(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    data: T


class StringModel(BaseModel[str]):
    pass


model = StringModel(data="data")
model.data = "other data"
```

I am getting the following mypy error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "T")  [assignment]
    model.data = "other data"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems to be an issue with the `pydantic.mypy` mypy plugin because when I remove it, I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Please provide your configuration and `mypy` version. With `mypy==1.3.0` (compiled) and `pydantic==1.10.7` I get from `mypy a.py --strict` the expected output: "Success: no issues found in 1 source file"

Comment: If your `mypy` is ancient, please try upgrading.

Comment: same versions as you. I tried in a different venv with just pydantic and mypy and you are correct, there is no issues. I will try to pin down what is causing this.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, it seems to be an issue with the pydantic.mypy plugin. When I remove it, the error goes away. Now I need to figure out what I lose by removing the plugin.

Comment: And seems like there is an open issue for it as well https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/5611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with the pydantic.mypy plugin
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/5611